# Adding 65M Records to Cassandra / Scylla Via Node.js

Tags: node.js, cassandra, scylla

I have a Cassandra table with 2 columns. Column 1 is the primary key. It's a string. The second is a set of strings.

I have a text file of 65m records. I'm trying to plug scylla with these records. After running this for a while, Scylla tells me that 2048 requests are inflight and the server is busy. I feel like this shouldn't be happening. Using async / await, this code theoretically should wait until the record persists until moving onto the next line, not throwing requests out.

How do I fix this?

```
const cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');

const client = new cassandra.Client({
    localDataCenter: 'us-east',
    contactPoints: ["ec2-54-90-217-211.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9042"],
    keyspace: 'default_keyspace',
});

const readInterface = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('./domains'),
    output: null,
    console: false
});

readInterface.on('line', async (line) => {
    const splitLine = line.split(',')

    const domain = splitLine[0]
    splitLine.shift()

    const query = `INSERT INTO domains (domain, ips) VALUES(?, ?);`;
    try {
      await client.execute(query, [ domain, splitLine ])
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
});
```

Comment: Use a stream for the client (instead of awaiting) might be that you’re hitting the upper limit of the buffer

Comment: It doesn't look like any of the requests are completing. Which is weird because they complete fine when it's one record only

Comment: readline.on is an async event handler, you are not waiting for the line processing to complete before moving on to the next line. if you are trying to load the entire file into scylla, it might be better to work with a readStream directly, and load X (say 200) lines in parallel into scylla. you want a certain degree of concurrency to make the load faster.
also you may want to look into prepared statements or batch statements as they can make the loading faster.